# How does 土口 match 'a person wearing a pendant'?

Tags: glyph-origin

Please see the green arrow beneath. I can't copy and paste from [Yellowbridge for 袁](https://www.yellowbridge.com/chinese/character-etymology.php?zi=%E8%A2%81):

[image]

Comment: What I read is the whole character 袁 looks like a picture of a person wearing a pendant. 口 in 袁 is like a pendant and 土 is more like the person's head and shoulder.

Comment: I'm not seeing any references to any pendants, I'm only seeing references to a person wearing clothes.

Comment: There is no pendant in the character. As to why Yellowbridge says there's a pendant, you'll have to find out where Yellowbridge references this explanation from.

Comment: @user3306356 Sorry. I was lazy in shirking the other text. Better?

Comment: What I meant was: in the resources I was flipping through I couldn’t find anything to cooborate what yellowbridge was saying about pendants.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no *pendant* in the character. 「袁」 (Mandarin: **yuán**) originally meant *to wear (clothes)*, where

- 「土」 is a corruption of 「又」, a *picture of a hand*, signifying the action of *wearing clothes*, and
- 「口」 is a corruption of 「〇」 (**yuán**), a phonetic hint.

  - 「〇」 is the shape of a *circle*, and this word is now written as 「圓」.

---

<kbd>[商](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shang_dynasty)
[甲](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oracle_bone_script)
[image]
[庫](http://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian/Reference/JiaguwenReference)1022
[合集33692](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/jgwhj/?bhfl=1&bh=33692&jgwfl=)</kbd>

「袁」 was originally 「⿰衣又」, which is an abstract depiction of [*a hand* 「又」](http://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian?kaiOrder=20) putting on [*robes* 「衣」](http://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian?kaiOrder=448). This word is now written as 「擐」 ([Baxter-Sagart OC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reconstructions_of_Old_Chinese#Baxter%E2%80%93Sagart_%282014%29): **/*[ɢ]ʷˤren-s/**).

> 「擐」 (*to wear, put on*) is made by
>
> 1. Adding on an additional semantic 「扌・手」
> 2. Complexifying 「袁」 to a pure phonetic 「瞏」 (something like **/*[ɢ]ʷˁ<r>en/**) by adding on 「目・罒」 to the top.
>
> 「瞏」 is systematically written as 「睘」 today across all characters.

「⿰衣又」 had a few variants, produced by some small modifications in two main ways:

- Sometimes, multiple 「又」 were included, and 「又」 at the top was further corrupted into [「止」](http://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian?kaiOrder=141).

  <kbd>商
  甲
  [image]
  [1648](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/jgwhj/?bhfl=6&bh=1648&jgwfl=)
  懷特甲骨集</kbd><kbd>商
  甲
  [image]
  [存](http://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian/Reference/JiaguwenReference)・下506
  [合集31774](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/jgwhj/?bhfl=1&bh=31774&jgwfl=)</kbd>
- Other times, 「〇」 (**/*ɢʷ<r>en/**) was added as a phonetic hint.

  <kbd>商
  甲
  [image]
  [寧滬](http://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian/Reference/JiaguwenReference)1.501
  [合集27756](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/jgwhj/?bhfl=1&bh=27756&jgwfl=)</kbd><kbd>商
  甲
  [image]
  [2061](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/jgwhj/?bhfl=3&bh=2061&jgwfl=) (⿰彳袁)
  小屯南甲骨</kbd>

> 「〇」 is the shape of a *circle*, and this word is now written as 「圓」.

Both of these modifications were eventually incorporated:

<kbd>[西周](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Western_Zhou)
[金](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_bronze_inscriptions)
[image]
史墻盤 (遠)
[集成10175](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/yzjwjc/?bh=10175&jgwfl=)</kbd>

Later,

- 「止」 merged with the top part of 「衣」 and was further corrupted into 「土」
- 「〇」 was systematically corrupted into 「口」 across all Chinese characters

<kbd>[秦](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qin_dynasty)
[簡](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bamboo_and_wooden_slips)
[image]
秦律十八87 (遠)
[睡虎地秦簡](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shuihudi_Qin_bamboo_texts)</kbd><kbd>今
[楷](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_script)
[image]</kbd>

---

**References:**

- 季旭昇《說文新證》
- [殷墟甲骨文中の「遠」「（邇）」と関連字](http://kirara0048.blogspot.com/2018/01/blog-post_15.html)
- [小學堂](http://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/)
- [國學大師](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/)

  - [郭沫若《甲骨文合集》](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/jgwhj/)
  - [中國社會科學院考古研究所《殷周金文集成》](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/yzjwjc/)
  - [許進雄《懷特氏等收藏甲骨文集》](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/jgwhj/?bhfl=6&bh=&jgwfl=)
  - [中國社會科學院考古研究所《小屯南地甲骨》](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/jgwhj/?bhfl=3&bh=&jgwfl=)
- [漢語多功能字庫](http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/)

Answer (score 0):

**袁**

说文解字:

長衣皃。此字之本義。今衹謂爲姓。而本義廢矣..

皃: 通"貌"

Translation:

Looking of long cloths. This is the original meaning. Today only used as surname. The original meaning is deprecated...

No pendant mentioned...

bone script
[image]